# Send AWS CLI commands using HTTPS requests instead

Tags: httprequest, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am currently interacting with an AWS service using AWS CLI in terminal or bash and that works well. I however wish to implement a convenience application to do that interaction and Im guessing there is some public HTTP requests API by AWS?

How do I do this? I cannot find any documentation or resource on this?
The application I wish to implement is a Mac app. Im guessing the command parameters would be specified through json. However, I have no idea on the URL signature.

An example AWS CLI command is:

```
aws devicefarm list-uploads --arn arn-123-nra --type FILE
```

How do I do the same with an HTTPS request?

Answer (score 1):

It is not straightforward to do this. AWS APIs currently use a signing process, known as [SIGv4](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html) to authenticate AWS customers to services. The AWS SDKs / CLI serve as a way to simplify this so that you do not have to do this yourself.

If you really want to get into solving this problem yourself, you should look into the [sigv4 signing documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html). Otherwise, I strongly recommend just using the [AWS SDKs in your preferred language](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/).